# Hide a table row with knockout style binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

I want to bind the display-style of a table row with knockout.js to a viewmodel property. I have to use the binding, because I want to hide or show the table row depending on other properties in my viewmodel.

Sample HTML code:

```
<tr data-bind="style: myProperty">
    Test
</tr>
```

The viewModel:

```
this.myProperty = ko.computed(() => {
    return "{ display: none }";
});
```

But this doesn't work. The property is entered after loading the page, but the table row is still displayed. Is there another way to do this or did I forgot something?

Comment: Why do you need a `computed` if you don't access any other observable in it? Why don't use the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding? Anyway the style binding takes an object and not a string so you need to write: `this.myProperty = ko.computed(() => {
    return { display: "none" };
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "visible" binding instead. More details [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

Your example may looks like:

```
<tr data-bind="visible: myProperty">
    Test
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, I've found another solution:

According to the documentation at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html I set the style now this way:

```
<tr data-bind="style: { display: !TrueOrFalseProperty() ? 'none' : 'inline' }">
   Test
</tr>
```

This works.

Comment: The use of `visible: myProperty` changes the `display` style of the element, but with a terse, robust and readable binding. I would recommending using the answer given by @SBirthare

Comment: Yeah, this is wrong.  You really should use the visible binding.  Also, your initial approach was better than in-lining the logic in the html.  You were just missing the quotes around 'none'.  Knockout is great once you see the subtle advantages to doing it the "right" way.